# Grouping SQL query to hard code column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have columns and
 Date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

```
 Date          Description.    Id.       Amt
01/01/2000.       ABC.       D1.     100 
02/01/2000.       XYZ.       R1      100
01/01/2000.       PQR.       D1.     100
01/02/2000.       CDF.       D1.     150
```

Now I need query to display

```
Date          Description.    Id.      Amt
01/01/2000.       ABC.       D1.    200
02/01/2000.       XYZ.       R1     100
01/02/2000.       CDF.       D1.    150
```

I need to group by date and sum the amount. But I also need to hard code the description value ABC of my choice.

Comment: Do you mean hardcode `description` for a group? What should be the order? for `01/01/2000`, amond `ABC` and `PQR`, why you want `ABC`? Alphabetically? Also don't you want to group by `id` ? If not then which `id` should you display if they are different for a group?

Comment: I want to group by date only, not by id. It is not ABC OR PQR I should be able to use my own hardcoded text 'X0000 ' when I have similar dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` with aggregation to hardcode the description when group size is more than one row.:

```
select the_date,
    id,
    case 
        when count(*) > 1
            then 'ABC'
        else max(description)
        end as description,
    sum(amt) as amt
from your_table
group by the_date,
    id
```

Also, note that I called the `date` column as `the_date` as `date` is a reserved keyword. So, avoid using that or escape it using double quotes (I'd just use some other name).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need based on your expected output. But you might want to check on `min(description)` which you say you want to hardcode. Also `min(id) is assuming that`id`is same for same`date`. But if it is different, the you have to decide which`id` you want to show.

```
select date,
min(description), --assuming you want it alphabatically.
min(id), --assuming they are same for a group. If they are different, the dispay alphabatically.
sum(amt)
from your_table
group by date
```